# IdentityServer4, Swift iOS App and External Identity Provider

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4, appauth

IdentityServer newbie here....

I am building a mobile app and would like to provide the end user the ability to sign in using SSO for users that have a corporate identity provider and my company as the identity provider for those that don't have an identity provider.

it's possible that over time we add more external identity providers.

We have an on premise identityServer4 already installed and configured and only using it for client credentials for our API->API communications.

We also have an Azure Active Directory tenant with all of our AD accounts (our internal corporate accounts).

Here is what I would like to do (if possible of course):

- Have the mobile app (swift and android, but for now let's just discuss swift) be completely unaware of any external identity providers and have it point to our on-premise identity server for authentication.
- Add external identity providers in identity server
- Control what external identity providers we "add" all on the backend and not have the UI layer concerned with specific external providers, but have the identity server redirect accordingly.
- Not bother the user to have to select which provider to use  (if I am a corporate user with an external IDP configured, it should automatically take me to MY e-idp login page, if not then present my own login page)

I am also open to the idea of using Azure identity management as the identity provider and add external identity providers there.

What about Azure B2C?

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can check this app integrated with AppAuth for iOS. [Link in GitHub](https://github.com/edihasaj/openid-client-ios-appauth)